# How to run code on Application opens in Android?

Tags: oncreate, android

My Android app need the user to create an account to be able to use the app. The account info is stored in SQLite database. When the application starts I check if the user has an account, if not I show a sign up activity for the user.

Now I get reports from users that they sometimes comes to the sign up activity even if they've already created an account. This happens when they've closed the application and reopen it again.

This is the code I'm using and I need to figure out what the problem might be:

```
//MyApplication.java
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private DataBaseUtility dbu;
    public boolean hasAccount;  

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //Init sqlite database
        this.dbu = new DataBaseUtility(this);

        //This loads the account data from the database and returns true if the user has already created an account
        this.hasAccount = loadAccount();
    }

    public boolean loadAccount() {
        boolean loadedData = false;

        String query = "SELECT data FROM tblaccount WHERE tblaccount.deleted=0";
        Cursor cursor = this.dbu.getCursor(query);
        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                loadedData = true;
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

        return loadedData;
    }
}

//MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MyApplication application = (MyApplication)getApplication();
        if (!application.hasAccount) {
            //Take the user to the sign up activity
        }
}
```

My idea is that maybe sometimes `MainActivity.onCreate()` runs before `MyApplication.onCreate()`.  Can that be the case?

Comment: Are you sure your loadAccount() method always works properly? Can you post it's code?

Comment: You can try printing something in Logcat to see what method is called first.

Comment: Yeah, I'm quite sure, it only uses the DataBaseUtility to load the data from the sqlite database. So as far as the sqlite database is initialized it should work.

Comment: Alex I haven't ever had this problem myself, have tried to open and close the app many many times and it always work like it should, so it is hard to reproduce.

Comment: So only some users experience it, the question is, on what phones? Maybe the connection to database is working slow, and takes some time to load.

Comment: Yes, it seems that it is not happening for everybody. I know one running samsung galaxy GT-I9000. Can't I always be sure that MyApplication.onCreate() runs before MainActivity.onCreate()?

Comment: `MyApplication.onCreate()` runs first but `this.hasAccount = loadAccount();` may not have any effect. Is there a thread in there? Can we see the code for `loadAccount()` ?

Comment: Maybe it is only code excerpt but maybe move hasAccount to MainActivity if it is the one that suppose to us it.

Comment: I added the code of the loadAccount() to the question. There is no threads or something like that.

Comment: Greg I need to have hasAccount in MyApplication as I need to use it all around the app. But maybe I should move the check to MainActivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `application`'s `onCreate`, you are checking if the user has an account and setting a boolean.

You are checking in the `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` if the user has an account through the `application`'s boolean.

`application`'s `onCreate()` executing before `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` is **always** the case! It is impossible for a different execution path to occur and since `application`'s `onCreate()` does not have a `Runnable` it is a 100% garantuee.

Please make sure you're `DataBaseUtility` does not have any Runnables.

Anyway **STILL** there are several ways to reproduce the error! I will not state these now but you can know them when you see:

**SOLUTION**

`MainActivity` You have forgotten to update `application.hasAccount` upon successfull sign up~

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MyApplication application = (MyApplication)getApplication();
        if (!application.hasAccount) {
            //Take the user to the sign up activity
            //if(successful) application.hasAccount = true
        }
}
```

**To avoid database exceptions**

I use this:

**REMARK** It would be much better to use more strong persistent status saving for the database -i.e. `SharedPreferences`

```
boolean isOpened = false;
//When I need to open
if(!isOpened){
    //open
    isOpened = true;
}
//When I need to close
if(isOpened){
    //close
    isOpened = false;
}

onDestroy() {  //every onDestroy
    if(isOpened){
        //close
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So I can always be sure that application's onCreate() runs first, thats good. I save the user info in the sqlite database on successful signup. Then I set hasAccount = True, so that is not the case. There are thousands of users running the application and this errors seems to happen only for a few users. As I relay on the sqlite database stored on the device, maybe the problem is that it has been removed or is corrupt?

Comment: it can not go corrupt? Are you sure you are closing database? sometime if you do not close database (even if the app was closed using force close) next time you try to open, exception occurs! Did you try `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not closing the database. I only have one open connection in DataBaseUtility that I use through the whole app. So when should I close it, when the app closes?

Comment: Thanks! As I only open the database once in application's onCreate and keep it open do I put this code in the DataBaseUtility or in MyApplication?

Comment: No put it in *MyApplication*. Try to reproduce the error and see if the user will get sign-up screen

Comment: But Application doesn't seem to have an onDestroy method? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: Ah yeah application doesnt have onDestroy()... In each block of code, when you are done, close the database

Comment: So I need to open and close the database every time I use it in an activity? I thought I could keep the connection open through the application with DataBaseUtility. Now I need to rewrite my whole app. Maybe I can just close the database on MainActivity.onDestroy() as this activity is always in the background of my app?

Comment: Yes close it.. Anyway try to simulate if database is not closed ! and force close app then open .. there must be an exception

Comment: Yeah, I've tried like thousands time to reproduce this problem that some users have but I never have this problem when I test.